# jQuery html() returns empty of new input tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I want to generate some input tags dynamically. I've tried this:

```
var x = $('<input/>').prop({type:'checkbox'}).prop({checked:true});
var y = x.html();

//x is a jquery object which contains 1 object.
//y always get empty string.
```

Comment: `.html()` does not select the element itself, it selects *its inner content*. Your `<input />` has no inner content, therefore `html()` will return nothing.

Answer (score 3):

`html()` gets the HTML *contents* of the first element in the set of matched elements and not the outer HTML.

You can use `outerHTML` of the first element to get the html.

```js
var x = $('<input/>').prop({type:'checkbox'}).prop({checked:true});
var y = x[0].outerHTML;
 
console.log( y );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```